# Firefox localStorage how to access it across all tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am only concerned with mozilla's use of **localStorage**. When i store strings into **localStorage**

example:

on tab A, I insert:

```
localStorage["item"] = "hello";
```

on tab B, I request the same item using

```
localStorage.getItem("item");
```

I cannot access this item for some reason in Tab B if i set the the value in Tab A, however i have used the same code in **Google Chrome** before and it has shown **Global** characteristics.. why does it not work in **Mozilla Firefox** the same way?? Other stackoverflow threads have said to use **globalStorage** but that is a deprecated method according to documentation.

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Are tab A and tab B open to pages on the same origin? (i.e., same protocol and domain name)?

Comment: hey they are different origins. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you may try is to set the `localStorage` value as:

```
localStorage.setItem("item", "hello");
```

or

```
localStorage.item = "hello"
```

According to the specification all documents with the same origin share the same `localStorage` data (regardless of the origin of the scripts that actually access `localStorage`). They can read each other’s data. And they can overwrite each other’s data. But documents with different origins can never read or overwrite each other’s data (even if they’re both running a script from the same third-party server).

This means that you should be able to access the same `localStorage` date from different tabs.

Comment: hmm, how come it works in chrome across tabs in the same browser.. but mozilla just seems tab specific.. e.g. if i go to youtube and i alert all the contents of localStorage it only shows youtube specific and ignores the fact that i have set variables from other domains on other tabs.

Comment: @Aiden I'm also having the same issue in firefox. Did you find a solution for this? Everything works fine in chrome.

Comment: @mrudult I tracked this down for a user just now - it appears like it may be caused by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453699