# local storage HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if its possible to use local storage on a other page. I need to use the clicks in another page. Dont know how to do it or if its even possible.  If you can help me out it would be nice. Its still for my school project.

Many thanks in advance.

```js
function clickCounter() {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="result" style ="color: white;"></div>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
```

Comment: Yes you can use it simply by calling `localStorage.clickcount`. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Check it this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238404/firefox-localstorage-how-to-access-it-across-all-tabs/19238846#19238846

Answer (score 1):

The [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is shared between all pages of the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin).

So, assuming they're all pages of your site served from one origin, there's no problem in sharing those data.

Note: all pages served in `file://` are considered as from different origins. You need a web server (which may be on localhost) to test.